# Second derivative of a log function

Tags: calculus, statistics

I am trying to calculate the Fisher Information (covariance matrix) for categorical random variable. I can calculate the first and the second derivatives of the following function, but to calculate their joint second derivative, I got lost. Can anyone explain how to derive off diagonal entries of covariance matrix?

$\frac{dev^2L}{dev_pdev_(1-p)}$ $\log(p) + \log(1-p)$ =

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. It seems I made a mistake in my question. I am calculating covariance matrix for categorical random variable using Fisher Information and got stuck in calculating off-diagonal entries of it. I know the answer, but do not understand how to derive them.